# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} ({x(1+x) \over 2}) ^ {1 \over x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{x\to\infty} ({x(1+x) \over 2}) ^ {1 \over x}$

okay so the initial limit was the n-th rooth of 1+2+...+n so I thought it was easier using the formula for the sum. then because $(x(1+x))^{1 \over x} > 0$ I tried to calculate the limit of the numerator and denumerator but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you compute the limit of the (natural) logarithm of the sequence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x+\log(1+x)-\log2}{x}
$$
and this is easily seen to be $0$: in general
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(a+x)}{x}=0
$$
which you can prove in several ways, including l'Hôpital.

Thus your limit is $e^0=1$.

Comment: oh thank you! I must have complicated myself unnecessarely.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints** Let \begin{equation}
y=
\lim_{x\to\infty} ({x(1+x) \over 2}) ^ {1 \over x}
\end{equation}
Taking **log** both sides,
\begin{equation}
\text{log}y=\frac{1}{x}\text{log}\lim_{x\to\infty} ({x(1+x) \over 2})
\end{equation}

Now you can proceed.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x(x+1)}2\right)^{1/x}=\dfrac{\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}}{\lim_{x\to\infty}2^{1/x}}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}\right)^{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {x+1}x}$$

Now use apply L'Hospital or use [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-5-exploring-the-infinite/part-a-lhospitals-rule-and-improper-integrals/session-90-advanced-examples-of-lhospitals-rule/MIT18_01SCF10_ex90sol.pdf)  on $$\lim_{y\to\infty}y^{1/y}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left({x(1+x) \over 2}\right) ^ {1 \over x}= {x^\frac1x(1+x)^\frac1x \over 2^\frac1x}$$

with

$$x^\frac1x= e^{\frac{\log x}x}\to e^0 =1$$

$$(1+x)^\frac1x= e^{\frac{\log (1+x)}x}\to e^0 =1$$

$$2^\frac1x= e^{\frac{\log 2}x}\to e^0 =1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x\ge1$ we have

$$1={1(1+1)\over2}\le{x(x+1)\over2}\le{x(x+x)\over2}=x^2$$

and thus

$$1\le\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x(x+1)\over2\right)^{1/x}\le\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}\right)^2$$

The upper bound limit, $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}$, is easily seen to equal $1$, so the squeeze theorem says the requested limit is also equal to $1$.

For completeness, and also for its own sake, let's show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1$ without using logs or L'Hopital, just some algebra and standard properties of limits.

First, let's prove that $k^{1/n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $k\ge1$. Clearly $1\le k^{1/(n+1)}\le k^{1/n}$, so $k^{1/n}$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below, and hence has a limit, say $\ell\ge1$. From

$$\sqrt{\ell}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}k^{1/n}\right)^{1/2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}k^{1/2n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}k^{1/m}=\ell$$

we see that $\ell=1$.

Next, note that the binomial theorem and an inequality of binomial coefficients tells us

$$(n+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}n^{n-k}\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}n^kn^{n-k}+n\cdot n+1=n^n(n-1)+n^2+1\le n^{n+1}\quad\text{for }n\ge3$$

so that $1\le(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}\le n^{1/n}$ (for $n\ge3$), which implies $n^{1/n}$ is also a decreasing sequence bounded below, and hence also has a limit, say $L\ge1$. This time we have

$$\sqrt L=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}\right)^{1/2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n)^{1/2n}/\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt2^{1/n}=L/1=L$$

and so $L=1$ as well.

Finally, for arbitrary real number $x\ge1$,

$$1\le x^{1/x}\le(2\lfloor x\rfloor)^{1/\lfloor x\rfloor}\to1\text{ as }\lfloor x\rfloor\to\infty$$